# How do I get the good future music in Sonic CD?

Tags: sonic-cd

I will record all the music from the game Sonic CD but I noticed that Zone 3 of a level is the same music as the previous zones in the future.

Can someone tell me how to get the good future music? I am very confused and as far as I understand every level (not zone) has 4 tracks: past, present, future good and future bad. Is this how it is? Also I heard that the past music in Japan is the same as the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the Good Future in Act 3, you have to get the Good Future in both Acts 1 and 2.  This is done by destroying the Robot Generator in the Past in each of the first two Acts.

Note that the Good Future music doesn't play for very long in Act 3 as Act 3 is the boss act which plays the Boss music once the battle starts.

As for the music, on the Sega CD version of the game, the Past tracks were done on the Genesis sound chip.  All other music, including the Present, Bad Future, and Good Future tracks are all CD Audio.

While Spencer Nilson, et al redid the CD Audio tracks, they didn't redo the Genesis synthesizer tracks.  Which is why the Past music is the same in all regions.

Incidentally the [PlayStation 3](http://www.playstation.com/en-us/games/sonic-cd-ps3/), [Xbox 360](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Sonic-CD/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802584111f1), and [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/200940/) releases of Sonic CD let you choose whether you want the North America music or the Japanese/Europe music... although the Japanese vocal songs did get replaced with instrumental versions, presumably due to contracts expiring.

Comment: So going into the future in act 1 is the same track as simply going into act 3 before the boss?

Comment: @NickBailuc Yes, Act 3's stage doesn't have its own music... it uses either the Bad Future or Good Future music depending on whether you unlocked the Good Future.

Comment: Incidentally, only the Past tracks use the Genesis synth.  Everything else is CD Audio.  Obviously, for the re-release, it uses audio files for all of them but the Past music was still recorded from the Genesis sound synth to make that audio file.  This happened with the original PC version of the game from the late 90s too.

Comment: The Sega CD model 2  I am using has a headphone port in the back. It says mixing. What's it for do you know?